# How to use Sybase LOAD TABLE correctly?

Tags: sybase, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I have been using ISQL (SQLAnywhere 12) to import data from CSVs into existing tables using INPUT INTO and never ran into a problem. Today I needed to import data into a table containing an auto-increment column, however, and thought I just needed to leave that column blank, so I tried it with a file containing only 1 row of data (to be safe). Turns out it imported with a 0 in the auto-increment field instead of the next integer value.

Looking at the [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315750.htm), it seems like I should be using LOAD TABLE instead, but the examples look a bit complex.

My questions are the following...

- The documentation says the CSV file needs to be on the database server and not the client. I do not have access to the database server itself - can I load the file from within ISQL remotely?
- How do I define the columns of the table I'm loading into? What if I am only loading data into a few columns and leaving the rest as NULL?
- To confirm, this will leave existing data in the table as-is and simply add to it using whatever is in the CSV?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. Check out the [online documentation](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1201/en/dbreference/load-table-statement.html*d5e54994) for `LOAD TABLE` - you can use the `USING CLIENT FILE` clause.
2. You can specify the column names in parens after the table name, i.e. `LOAD TABLE mytable (col1, col2, col3) USING CLIENT FILE 'mylocalfile.txt'`. Any columns not listed here will be set to NULL if the column is nullable or the equivalent to an empty string if it's not - this is why your autoincrement column was set to 0. You can use the `DEFAULTS ON` clause to get what you want.
3. Yes, existing data in the table is not affected.

Comment: Thank you so much. One follow up question - in the doc, some of the examples use filler() in the column list. What does that do?

Comment: It's used when you have a csv file with more columns of data than you want to import. Say you have a file with 4 columns but you don't need the third one. You would use `LOAD TABLE mytable (col1, col2, filler(), col4) ...` to skip the third column.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks again!